# How do I optimize and make my code look easier

Tags: python

I'm a begginer to python and I have started using pygame to make a bezier curve program where you can move the points around and it will show the curve. While making it, I thought that it could be heavily optimized since there are a lot of nested if statements and I would like to have more readable code as well as it is kind of a mess.

```
import sys, pygame, time
pygame.init()

def set_pixel(surface, x, y, r, g, b):
    surface.set_at((x, y), (r, g, b))

def bezier_curve(p1, p2, p3, p4, t):
    x = (1-t)**3*p1[0] + 3*(1-t)**2*t*p2[0] + 3*(1-t)*t**2*p3[0] + t**3*p4[0]
    y = (1-t)**3*p1[1] + 3*(1-t)**2*t*p2[1] + 3*(1-t)*t**2*p3[1] + t**3*p4[1] # some gnarly math from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve into python syntax

    return [x, y]

def length(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)**0.5

def main():
    size = width, height = 800, 600
    lerp_amount = 0.001

    black = 0, 0, 0
    white = 255, 255, 255
    brighter_blue = 0, 200, 200

    point_circle_size = 7

    p1 = (point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size)
    p2 = (point_circle_size, point_circle_size)
    p3 = (width - point_circle_size, point_circle_size)
    p4 = (width - point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size)

    mouseX = 0
    mouseY = 0

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    while True:
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if length(p1, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
                if (mouseX, mouseY) != p2 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p3 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p4:
                    p1 = (mouseX, mouseY)
            if length(p2, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
                if (mouseX, mouseY) != p1 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p3 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p4:
                    p2 = (mouseX, mouseY)
            if length(p3, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
                if (mouseX, mouseY) != p1 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p2 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p4:
                    p3 = (mouseX, mouseY)
            if length(p4, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
                if (mouseX, mouseY) != p1 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p2 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p3:
                    p4 = (mouseX, mouseY)

        draw_list = []
        lerp_t = 0
        continue_lerp = True
        while continue_lerp:
            lerp_t += lerp_amount
            draw_list.insert(0, bezier_curve(p1, p2, p3, p4, lerp_t))

            if lerp_t > 1:
                continue_lerp = False

        screen.fill(black)
        continue_draw_list = True
        draw_list_index = 0
        while continue_draw_list:
            try:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, brighter_blue, draw_list[draw_list_index], draw_list[draw_list_index + 1], 3)
            except:
                continue_draw_list = False
            draw_list_index += 1

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p1, point_circle_size, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p2, point_circle_size, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p3, point_circle_size, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p4, point_circle_size, 0)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, p1, p2, 1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, p3, p4, 1)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to python! I also started wth the language a few months ago and love it, particularly if you try to do things in a pythonic way - it just *feels* right. You're obviously not new to programming so here a few more advanced ideas for clean, idiomatic programming:

### One variable for one entity

Where you have variables like `p1`, `p2`, ... they are usually all aspects of the same *thing* or entity. Python gives you some great ways to treat this as a single variable. The most basic is a `list`, a `dict` would give you a chance to name the individual entries - at the cost of having them returned in a guaranteed sorted order.

```
p1 = (point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size)
p2 = (point_circle_size, point_circle_size)
p3 = (width - point_circle_size, point_circle_size)
p4 = (width - point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size)
```

Can then become

```
points = [
    (point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    (point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    (width - point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    (width - point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    ]
```

You'll then need to remember that zero-indexing means `p1` is now `points[0]`

### Use Python's built in iteration capabilities

Python has awesome iteration support - it's one of the first *pythonic* things I picked up. `For` could really be called `for each`. So now you have a `points` you can update

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p1, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p2, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p3, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p4, point_circle_size, 0)
```

to

```
for point in points:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, point, point_circle_size, 0)
```

Other great things to look at in general are `enumerate`, which I'll use in an example later to simplify your nested `if`s and `zip`

### Get to know and use the standard libraries

There are a few libraries which offer stuff that is not built-in but is "almost". Two key ones to learn about first are `collections` and `itertools`. (You'll find the documentation with the central python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html and here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

From `collections` there are two which could be useful for you: `namedtuple` and `deque` (double-ended Queue).

`namedtuple` lets you assign names to the indices of a tuple. This could be useful for your `points` (it's actually the example given int he docstring for namedtuple!):

```
points = [
    (point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    (point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    (width - point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    (width - point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    ]
```

can become:

```
from collections import namedtuple
...

...
coord = namedtuple("coord", [x,y])
...

...
points = [
    coord(point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    coord(point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    coord(width - point_circle_size, point_circle_size),
    coord(width - point_circle_size, height - point_circle_size),
    ]
```

then you can reference them using normal indexing or also as `points[0].x` and `points[0].y`

So for example the `bezier_curve` calculation would start:

```
x = (1-t)**3*p[0].x + 3*(1-t)**2*t*p[1].x + ...
```

`Deque` is what to use if you find yourself using `.insert(0, ...)`. Tuples and lists are optimised as FILO - so `.append` and `.pop` work great but `.insert(0, ...)` is slow as the system needs to rearrange everything in memory. A `deque` is optimised for access at both ends.

I'd suggest using a `deque` for `draw_list`:

```
from collections import deque
...

...
draw_list = deque()
...

...
    draw_list.appendleft(bezier_curve(p1, p2, p3, p4, lerp_t))
...
```

### Extract functions to make your code easier to read

This is valid in any language, I find it very valid in python as good python code reads like english sentences.

All your nested `if` statements:

```
if length(p1, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
    if (mouseX, mouseY) != p2 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p3 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p4:
        p1 = (mouseX, mouseY)
if length(p2, [mouseX, mouseY]) < point_circle_size:
    if (mouseX, mouseY) != p1 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p3 or (mouseX, mouseY) != p4:
        p2 = (mouseX, mouseY)
```

have a general form and so can be extracted to a function with a well-chosen name (you can probably do better than me at naming it and the variables):

```
def near(mouse, coords, i, fuzz):
    return ((length(coords[i], mouse) < fuzz) and (mouse = coords[i] or mouse not in coords)
```

which lets you simplify the original code to

```
for i, c in enumerate(points):
    if near(mouse, c, i, point_circle_size):
        c = mouse
```

This is assuming you have used the tip above to put all your points into one list and noticed that `mouseX, mouseY` could simply be `mouse`
i.e.:

```
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

or (if you have implemented `coords` as a `namedtuple`):

```
mouse = coords(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

### Uses classes where they make sense

Having done all that, take a look at the idea of using a class to let you group functionality and variables together in a meaningful way.
Your code would lend itself to mainly being part of a `class bezier_curve(object)` which has attributes such as `points`, internal attributes such as `_draw_list` and methods such as `calc_curve(self, t)`, `lerp(self)` and `update_points(self, mouse)`.
If that is enough of a pointer to follow then great. If you'd like a few more specific tips, just comment.

### Overall

I'm a fan of clean code, TDD and idiomatic programming. Python is, IMHO, a great language to practice all three to create expressive code that reads like a set of instructions where each line is an english sentence.
In general, don't worry too much about trying to plan all these kind of ideas in to your coding from the start:

1. Start by writing code in some way that works, however ugly
2. Make sure you are creating and extending test cases up front, just-in-time as you go - that will already guide you towards creating smaller functions and methods that *do one thing each* and mean that you can refactor afterwards without any fear - just hit the *go* button on your tests after every small change.
3. Then "do a Raymond": hit the table and think "There must be a better way"(*), refactor, refactor, refactor until you can read your code easily and it looks nice

(*) - search youtube for videos from Raymond Hettinger if you are interested in learning python this way - he's great to listen to and imparts amazing advice. A good one to start with would be: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go

Most importantly - have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I would say this

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p1, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p2, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p3, point_circle_size, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, p4, point_circle_size, 0)
```

Can be written as

```
for i in {p1, p2, p3, p4}:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, i, point_circle_size, 0)
```

Comment: Or just *for i in p1, p2, p3, p4* - i.e., no need to create a set. Although this makes the code shorter/cleaner it won't make any measurable difference to performance

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Honestly I forgot that for loops exist when creating this and used while loops instead

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if the bezier_curve function will benefit in terms of [measurable] performance but the code could be reduced to:

```
def bezier_curve(p1, p2, p3, p4, t):
    mt = 1-t
    return [mt**3*pa + 3*mt**2*t*pb + 3*mt*t**2*pc + t**3*pd for pa, pb, pc, pd in zip(p1, p2, p3, p4)]
```

Comment: zip is the most understimated built-in function of Python, +1